# base_link not moving while replaying rosbag file in RViz

Tags: ros, rviz, base-odometry, base-link

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recorded a rosbag file with the following topics:
/ssl_slam/trajectory;
/tf;
/odom;
/initialpose;
/move_base_simple/goal;
/tf_static;

My goal is to replay the rosbag file in RViz and see the "map" axes, "base_link" axes, and green trajectory path drawn. Currently I am able to see only the map link axes and green trajectory path; the base_link axes do not move when I select them to be shown under "TF >> Frames". The base_link axes slowly fade away and leave only map axes and the green trajectory. How do I visualize the base_link axes so that they show how the robot actually moved while recording the rosbag file (want to see rotation and translation of the base_link axes).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404914/base_link-not-moving-while-replaying-rosbag-file-in-rviz/) by [hunterlineage1](https://answers.ros.org/users/110678/hunterlineage1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 24 on 2022-08-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `base_link` TF messages are time-stamped, so you need to make your setup repeat those prior timestamps when visualizing the data.

- You tell rosbag to publish to the `/clock` topic by specifying the `--clock` option.
- You also need to tell rviz to use the `/clock` topic. You do this by making sure the ros parameter `/use_sim_time` is set to `true` **before** the rviz node is started.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hunterlineage1](https://answers.ros.org/users/110678/hunterlineage1/) on 2022-08-16**:
Thank you so much!!! It worked perfectly. Really appreciate it